Telethon: Unable to Retrieve Text for Message (Album)
I am using the Telethon library to retrieve messages from a Telegram channel. I have a specific message that contains a photo and a caption (text), which I can see in the official Telegram application. However, when I fetch this message using Telethon, the message attribute appears to be empty.
Here is my code:
# python3.8
from telethon import TelegramClient

session_name = 'XXXX'
api_id = 999999
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'

async def main():
    chat = 1473001998
    message_id = 23420
    msg = await client.get_messages(chat, ids=message_id)
    print(msg.text)
    print(msg.message)
    #print(msg.stringify())

client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

The message field is empty, even though I see text in the Telegram app. I've tried the code with other messages, and it works fine. However, I think the problem with this message is because it looks like an Album message.
Am I missing something in how I access or retrieve the message? Is there a different attribute or method I should be using to get the message text for media messages?

Albums consist of more than one message. Any of those messages can have a caption (there can even be multiple captions inside an album). You'll need to fetch more than one message to find the caption.

Okay, I've found the text. Thank you!
As I understand, I should use grouped_id to join all of the messages together in one custom entity. But how can I understand that this exact message is the last for this group? Or I should expect that next message can be related to any previous group?

There can be messages outside an album in-between those that belong to an album. It is rare, but it can happen. You can't really know for sure when an album is "complete", but I've never seen more than one message being in-between an album. Different clients render these situations differently (some lie and show it as two albums, while some lie and show a single album, putting the in-between message either before or after).
